# Is there an API to find the latest version of the Facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is a bit meta but I'm wondering if there's an API to see what the latest version of the Facebook API is. Facebook changes/depricates their APIs pretty rapidly.

It would be nice if they had an API that could be used see what the latest version is that way we can keep our usage up to do date.

One option is to scrape the [changelog page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/) but that would assume the page will change less often than the api.

Comment: _“that way we can keep our usage up to do date”_ - and the actual point of that would be …? Making calls to lower API versions still works in general, and once a version gets shut down for good, all your calls will be implicitly upgraded to the next lowest version available to your app anyway. If anything, I think there’s some breakage potential, if you just slap the most current API version in automatically, without bothering what might have actually changed. […]

Comment: […] A newly deprecated feature might still work for quite a while using the API version the app was already on, whereas blindly updating to the newest one just for its own sake, might break things right then and there.

Comment: Ah apologies for not clarifying. It's more to notify devs of a new version being released rather than doing an automated upgrade.

Comment: Developers can subscribe to a lot of different updates under https://developers.facebook.com/settings/developer/contact/, such as for _“Version Deprecation - Alerts about a version upgrade affecting your app”_ or _“Platform Announcements - New products, events, surveys and more”_, maybe that helps a bit already.